# How to highlight words from JSON dictionary as user types them in text aeria, and replace them with their descriptions on form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, syntax-highlighting

I wonder how to having some JSON dictionary like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Ann.c",
        "realvalue": "./34534j435345j3b3"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ann.h",
        "realvalue": "./333dfsdGjh45j3b5"
    }

]
```

And text input where user enters into  something like: `gcc -o test Ann.c -lcrypto` into textaeria how to highlight `Ann.c` with some color and on form submition replace with its `realvalue`?

***Update:***
I am trying [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uDdbq/11/).. I know how to parse dictionary, but I can not make it highlight even simple word inside of form text input box=( (I try to use [this lib](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html))

So is such thing possible with text aeria and how to do it?

***Update:***
Wel I've done something kind of what will work for me using [this lib...](http://remysharp.com/2007/12/28/jquery-tag-suggestion/)

Comment: Highlighting inside the input element? What have you tried?

Comment: @Shef: link to my sketch provided... And yes - Highlighting inside the input element=)

Comment: I don't think you will ever be able to highlight a single word inside an input element. Maybe you can create like a flash/highlight effect on the whole element, but I doubt you will be able to do it for a single word.

Answer (score 1):

A not so cool method will be to change the entire innerHTML and and at the places u want highlights u can enter a div element with required color and specifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the syntax-ighlighting part by overlaying an element (such as a `<span>`) on top. It's probably best to generate and display the highlight on the 'blur' event and to hide the overlay when editing.

You can intercept the form submission with jquery and re-write the input values as needed. For example:

```
$('form#myform').submit(function() {
    $('input.syntaxhighlight', this).each(function() {
        this.value = highlight(this.value) ;   // call to 'highlight()' function.
    }) ;
}) ;
```